# Reducing battery use while using LocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am making a program that needs to check every 10 seconds the location

I do start the Location manager in the app delegate and leave it there:

```
// I need it to be precise
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

I’ve made a lot of research but didn’t find anything. Is there anything that would reduce the battery usage?

For example stopping the `LocationManager` everytime it recieves Location, and starting again when the 10 seconds passed and the program needs the location? Any suggesrions?

Comment: http://tumblr.twicetwice.net/post/47249353501/cllocationmanager-battery-saving-tips-and-best

Comment: iOS manages that for you, your app will be notified about any new location only when iOS _wants_ to notify your app – it does not matter whether your app wished to get a new location in every X seconds; iOS is not bothered; if you stop monitoring new locations, you will not have chance to restart the service while your app is in the background, iOS just suspends your app entirely.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main factors:

1. Location
2. Accuracy

First off, why do you need it every 10 seconds? That is VERY frequent.
How about every minute, or couple of minutes?

Secondly, do you need ten metre accuracy?
Reducing accuracy will allow the OS to save power.

The most power efficient way is to monitor significant location changes, like [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant_change_location_service).

Examine your use case. Allowing the OS to make more leeway will improve battery life. Asking for the most precise accuracy, at ten second intervals will drain it VERY quickly. Please post your use case in future when asking questions.

Comment: It is an app that checks if there are nearby pokemons (i have a database with pokemons located). And a polemon is only showing in a 100m distance: so it is important to at least know if the user’s location is +-10m because if it would be +-100m (Accuracy Nearest 100m) then it is possible that the user walks by a pokemon but because their last known location is not accure the pokemon wont shown. Thank you, I’ll try to fix the code with your idea somehow

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Can reduce accuracy - More will be accuracy more GPS power consumption is there for finding location even accuracy is nearestThreeKilometer is can give about 100 meter accuracy or so.   
       e.g locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers

1.  Use distance Filter instead time filter - e.g locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000 it will get called whenever location changed by 1000m.
2.  Don’t allow app to discover location is background  &  not enable background mode in capability
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false 

3. If GPS-level accuracy isn’t critical for your app, you don’t need continuous tracking, and region or visit monitoring isn’t more appropriate for your app, you can use the significant-change location service instead of the standard one
4. Use Request Location instead startUpdatingLocation() to get location one time only.e.g   self.locationManager.requestLocation()
5. You can help the determination of when to pause location updates by assigning a value to the activityType property. 
  locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
  // Specify the type of activity your app is currently performing
  locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.automotiveNavigation
```

`6. Defer Location Updates When Running in the Background` [Apple Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620547-allowdeferredlocationupdates)

`7.  Finally you can find Apple doc` [Location Best practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html)